# Creating a loop for protocol-type array

Tags: swift, class, types, syntax, protocols

I have this code:

```
protocol Animal {
    var type: String {get}
}

struct Dog: Animal {
    var name: String
    var type: String
    
    func bark() {
        print("Woof!")
    }
}

struct Cat: Animal {
    var name: String
    var type: String
       
    func meow() {
        print("Meow!")
    }
}

var bunty = Cat(name: "Bunty", type: "British Shorthair")
var nigel = Cat(name: "Nigel", type: "Russian Blue")
var percy = Cat(name: "Percy", type: "Manx")
var argos = Dog(name: "Argos", type: "Whippet")
var apollo = Dog(name: "Apollo", type: "Lowchen")

var animals: [Animal] = [bunty, nigel, percy, argos, apollo]
```

And the book gave me this task:

> «Make a loop that iterates through the animals in our Animal array, and see if you can figure out how to call either bark or meow, depending on whether the item in the array is a Dog or a Cat.»

I've come up with such solution:

```
for animal in animals {
    if let dog = animal as? Dog {
        dog.bark()
    } else if let cat = animal as? Cat {
        cat.meow()
    } else {
        print("Unknown animal type")
    }
}
```

But I'm wondering is there any way to complete the task simpler, without `as?` operator?

Comment: No, not really or at least not if you want to do it as the task requires. Otherwise a solution could be to add a function to the protocol, say makeNoice(), that each type implements by calling bark(), meow() etc.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several solutions to your problem, which might not necessarily be better or simpler. You'll find out that throughout your coding career, there is more than one way to bake a cake.

To start with, you could improve your current for loop by implementing a `switch` statement:

```swift
for animal in animals {
    switch animal {
    case let dog as Dog:
        dog.bark()
    case let cat as Cat:
        cat.meow()
    default:
        print("Unknown animal type")
    }
}
```

You could also make multiple loops and use yet another syntactic trick by using the `for case let` syntax:

```swift
for case let dog as Dog in animals {
    dog.bark()
}

for case let cat as Cat in animals {
    cat.meow()
}
```

Then, since you are using a protocol approach, you could solve this by implementing a new protocol `Soundable`. I've only implemented this on the `Dog`, but you should be able to add this to any animal that can make a sound:

```swift
/// This could also be defined as 
/// protocol Soundable: Animal
/// which would cause Soundable to also always be an animal
protocol Soundable {
    func makeSound()
}

struct Dog: Animal, Soundable {
    var name: String
    var type: String

    func makeSound() {
        print("Woof!")
    }
}

for animal in animals {
    (animal as? Soundable)?.makeSound()
}
// Or again with the for case let
for case let soundable as Soundable in animals {
    soundable.makeSound()
}
```

And then, lastly for this answer, subclassing. I feel like `Animal` also could be a `class`:

```swift
class Animal {
    var type: String = ""

    func makeSound() {}
}

class Dog: Animal {
    var name: String

    init(name: String, type: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.type = type
    }

    override func makeSound() {
        print("Woof!")
    }
}

class Cat: Animal {
    var name: String

    init(name: String, type: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.type = type
    }

    override func makeSound() {
        print("Meow!")
    }
}

for animal in animals {
    animal.makeSound()
}
```

##### Notable extra's

One can also use a `where` clause at the for loop, but this is only a `boolean guard` and thus does not cast the object to specified type:

```swift
for animal in animals where animal is Dog {
    // animal still is `Animal` here
    // but one should be able to safely cast to `Dog`
}
```

There's also the `compactMap` function, that will remove `nil` values from an array after performing the closure provided. This way, one could transform the previously mentioned `for case let` loop as well:

```swift
animals.compactMap { $0 as? Dog }.forEach { dog in
    dog.bark()
}
animals.compactMap { $0 as? Cat }.forEach { cat in
    cat.meow()
}
```

Then there's also the option of simply casting all at once, without any `if` or `switch` statement:

```swift
for animal in animals {
    (animal as? Dog)?.bark()
    (animal as? Cat)?.meow()
}
```

As you can see there are plenty of ways one could solve this issue. You could even mix and match solutions I provided above. See what fits you best. I really like the `switch` variant, but that only works well, when the set of animals remains small and therefor maintainable.

Comment: Thanks! Your knowledge will be very helpful for me :)

Answer (score 1):

The only other way I can see to accomplish this task is to make changes in `struct`'s themselves, like @JoakimDanielson said.

```
protocol Animal {
    var type: String { get }
    func makeSound()
}

struct Dog: Animal {
    var name: String
    var type: String
    
    func makeSound() {
        print("Woof!")
    }
}

struct Cat: Animal {
    var name: String
    var type: String
    
    func makeSound() {
        print("Meow!")
    }
}

var bunty = Cat(name: "Bunty", type: "British Shorthair")
var nigel = Cat(name: "Nigel", type: "Russian Blue")
var percy = Cat(name: "Percy", type: "Manx")
var argos = Dog(name: "Argos", type: "Whippet")
var apollo = Dog(name: "Apollo", type: "Lowchen")

var animals: [Animal] = [bunty, nigel, percy, argos, apollo]

for animal in animals {
    animal.makeSound()
}
```